# How to count and group sales, total by week ? AND how to display the data in the next week automatically?

Tags: mysql

I have the following (`MySQL`) table called "`sls_ord`":

```
Sales           Total                   Date
joko susilo     Rp. 12.000.000;     24-May-2013
wenini          Rp. 13.000.000;     25-May-2013
Supardjo        Rp. 13.300.000;     20-May-2013
wenini          Rp. 20.300.000;     6-May-2013
joko susilo     Rp. 23.300.000;     8-May-2013
joko susilo     Rp. 24.000.000;     1-May-2013
```

How to count and `group sales`, total by `week` ?

1 more question please help me,, how to display the data in the next week automatically ???

Comment: Can you explain `how to display the data in the next week automatically` with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 1st part of your question:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), WEEK(Date) FROM sls_ord GROUP BY WEEK(Date);
```

I am assuming that the `Date` field if of `Datetime` type

Also, as rightly said by @Raphael, you can add `YEAR(Date)` and `MONTH(Date)` in the `GROUP BY` and in the column list

Comment: I would add a YEAR(Date) and a MONTH(Date) in the GROUP clause

Comment: Are you using any scripting language?